# Trigger overlay with button on other page

Tags: javascript, html, button, hyperlink

I am trying to control an overlay function in HTML with an external js file and a second HTML page where the buttons are on.

So far it works when the buttons are on the same page. But I can not trigger the overlay from page 1 on page 2.

So the streaming page is the page where the viewer will be able to look and interact.

```
<div id="overlay" onclick="turnOverLayOff()">
         
        <div id="textContainer"><iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe5NWLPhYiLqM2YIUPCsVk3RB5h660Wei9eDGyKUhMMIB4iZw/viewform?embedded=true" width="640" height="415" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Laden…</iframe> </div>
         
    </div> 
    
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5A9v-n53LtI" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    
    <script src="overlay.js"></script>
```

Then the JS file is

```
    function turnOverLayOn(){
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
            }
function turnOverLayOff(){
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
            }
```

The second page from where I want to control the streamingpage from :

```
<div id="overlay" onclick="turnOverLayOff()">
        <div id="textContainer">Test tekst whatever </div>
    </div> 
    
    <div>
        <button onclick="turnOverLayOn()">Click here to turn ON </button>
    </div>
 

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5A9v-n53LtI" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    
    <script src="overlay.js"></script>
```

Comment: You would need a means of signalling between pages/tabs - one such method is the [BroadcastChannel api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API)

Answer (score 0):

As a means of signalling between the pages/tabs within the same browser you can use the `BroadcastChannel` api as mentioned in the comment above.

As demonstration - two basic HTML pages, both establish a connection to a common `Broadcast Channel` and one `listens` for messages from the other.

In the following the Video elements and iframes are commented out and replaced with simple text.

The `getStyle` function simply allows access programmatically to styles set on a named element and is used here to determine. The Javascript can be written to a single file and included in both pages as per the `external.js`...

**Page 1 - the page being controlled**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Page 1: streamingpage</title>
        <style>
            #overlay{display:block}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='overlay'>
            <div id='textContainer'>
                <!--<iframe src='https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe5NWLPhYiLqM2YIUPCsVk3RB5h660Wei9eDGyKUhMMIB4iZw/viewform?embedded=true' width='640' height='415' frameborder='0' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0'>Laden…</iframe>-->
                IFRAME CONTENT - docs.google.com
            </div>
        </div> 
        <!--<iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/5A9v-n53LtI' title='YouTube video player' frameborder='0' allow='accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture' allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
        VIDEO-YouTUBE
        <script>
        
            const getStyle=(n,css)=>{
                let style;
                if( window.getComputedStyle ){
                    style = window.getComputedStyle( n, null ).getPropertyValue( css );
                } else if( n.currentStyle ){
                    css = css.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function ( strMatch, p1 ){
                        return p1.toUpperCase();
                    });
                    style = n.currentStyle[ css ];
                } else {
                    style='';
                }
                return style;
            }
            
            let oChan=new BroadcastChannel( 'tabs' );
                oChan.addEventListener('message',(e)=>{
                    //inspect messages as they arrive
                    console.log( e.data );
                    
                    let div=document.getElementById('overlay');
                        div.style.display=getStyle(div,'display')=='block' ? 'none' : 'block';
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Page 2 - the page doing the controlling**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>page2: controller</title>
        <style>
            #overlay{display:block}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='overlay'>
            <div id='textContainer'>Test tekst whatever </div>
        </div>
        
        <div>
            <button id='toggler'>Click here to turn ON</button>
        </div>
        <!--<iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/5A9v-n53LtI' title='YouTube video player' frameborder='0' allow='accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture' allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
        VIDEO-YouTUBE
        
        <script>
        
            const getStyle=(n,css)=>{
                let style;
                if( window.getComputedStyle ){
                    style = window.getComputedStyle( n, null ).getPropertyValue( css );
                } else if( n.currentStyle ){
                    css = css.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function ( strMatch, p1 ){
                        return p1.toUpperCase();
                    });
                    style = n.currentStyle[ css ];
                } else {
                    style='';
                }
                return style;
            }
            
            
            
            let oChan=new BroadcastChannel( 'tabs' );
            
            sendmessage=function( data ){
                oChan.postMessage( { 'data':data } )
            };
            
            
            
            let bttn=document.querySelector('button#toggler');
                bttn.addEventListener('click',e=>{
                    let div=document.getElementById('overlay');
                        div.style.display=getStyle(div,'display')=='block' ? 'none' : 'block'
                        
                    /* 
                        send a message - the payload can be tailored to suit your needs and processed within the listener on page 1
                        this simply sends the `display` status of the local DIV but you can send whatever is meaningful/helpful.
                    */
                    sendmessage( { state:getStyle(div,'display') } );
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```